# Serial COM Port Selection by DropDownList in processing

Tags: drop-down-menu, processing, windows-7-x64, serial-communication

I wrote a program in `Processing 2.1.2` to establish a communication via serial Port between two machines. On my laptop, it was working fine but on my desktop where more than one serial ports are available, it is not detecting my functional  serial COM port.

So now I want them to appear on `Combo Button` and I will able to select one from them.

Can you guide me on how do I resolve this issue?

```
import processing.serial.*;

String input;
Serial port;

void setup() {
  size(448, 299,P3D);
  println(Serial.list());
  port = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  port.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  }

void serialEvent(Serial port)
{
 input = port.readString();
 if(input != null) {
   String[] values = split(input, " ");
   println(values[0]);
   println(values[1]);
   println(values[2]);
   } 
}
```

Comment: What com ports are you getting on your desktop ? Also, which one of these is the com port the serial device you want to use ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza  there are three COM ports are showing COM1 COM3 COM4... now I want them to appear on window and then I select functional one from the list... Is that possible in `Processing`..

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You will need to use a UI of your choice (either java's Swing components or a processing library like [controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, it is possible to use a UI library to display a dropdown. First you have to choose a library, like for example [controlP5](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/) which is very popular with Processing. You may choose to use Swing with a native look & feel or [G4P](http://www.lagers.org.uk/g4p/). That's totally up to you.

After that it should be a matter of plugging the serial ports list into the dropdown and opening the serial connection on the dropdown listener/callback.

Bellow is a proof of concept sketch based on the controlP5dropdownlist example that comes with the library:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;
DropdownList serialPortsList;

Serial serialPort;
final int BAUD_RATE = 9600;

void setup() {
  size(700, 400,P3D);

  String[] portNames = Serial.list();

  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  // create a DropdownList
  serialPortsList = cp5.addDropdownList("serial ports").setPosition(10, 10).setWidth(200);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < portNames.length; i++) serialPortsList.addItem(portNames[i], i);  
}


void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
  // DropdownList is of type ControlGroup.
  // A controlEvent will be triggered from inside the ControlGroup class.
  // therefore you need to check the originator of the Event with
  // if (theEvent.isGroup())
  // to avoid an error message thrown by controlP5.
  if (theEvent.isGroup()) {
    // check if the Event was triggered from a ControlGroup
    println("event from group : "+theEvent.getGroup().getValue()+" from "+theEvent.getGroup());
    //check if there's a serial port open already, if so, close it
    if(serialPort != null){
      serialPort.stop();
      serialPort = null;
    }
    //open the selected core
    String portName = serialPortsList.getItem((int)theEvent.getValue()).getName();
    try{
      serialPort = new Serial(this,portName,BAUD_RATE);
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error opening serial port " + portName);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
  else if (theEvent.isController()) {
    println("event from controller : "+theEvent.getController().getValue()+" from "+theEvent.getController());
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(128);
}
```

Also notice any existing connection will be closed when choosing a new serial port and errors handling opening the serial port are handled so the program doesn't crash in case there are issues.

For example, on OSX you get bluetooth serial ports, which may or may not be available or of use:

[image: serial ports list using controlP5 library]

Comment: it is working fine when I remove `P3D` from: `size(700, 400,P3D);` can you plz guide me Y it is not accepting `P3D`?

Comment: ? I'm slightly confused. The code should work using the ```P3D``` argument to ```size()``` or not. The controlP5 sample I started with had it and I didn't remove it, but feel free to use whatever fits your project better

Comment: Now I am facing same `P3D` problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376404/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-media-opengl-glexception-at-processing-ope

Comment: it's not the same problem, but thanks for pointing me to your other question ;)

Answer (score 1):

for processing 3.3.7 doesn't work at all for one string

```
  String portName = serialPortsList.getItem((int)theEvent.getValue()).getName();
```

So i spent a lot of my neurons and nervs, but my fix is getName change toString();
and

```
  String portName = serialPortsList.getItem((int)theEvent.getValue()).toString();
```

I don't understand why getName() gives me "The function doesnt exist" but toString works properly. Anybody can explain?

Answer (score 0):

1. For variable:

   ```
   String[] portNames = Serial.list();
   ```

   change to global variable:

   ```
   String[] portNames;
   ```
2. In:

   ```
   void setup()
   ```

   change:

   ```
   String[] portNames = Serial.list();
   ```

   to:

   ```
   portNames = Serial.list();
   ```
3. In code:

   ```
   String portName = serialPortsList.getItem((int)theEvent.getValue()).toString();
   ```

   change to:

   ```
   String portName =portNames.toString();
   ```