# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLException at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, raspberry-pi, processing, raspbian

I am writing a program in `Processing` on Raspberrypi(Raspbian), to import a `3D STL image` file. It is working perfectly on Microsoft (windows7) & Linux(Ubuntu) platform but I am struggling to run same program on Raspberrypi (Raspbian) platform.

I am getting below Error at `size(600,600,P3D)` when I run this program on Raspberrypi...

> Coding

```
import toxi.geom.*;
import toxi.geom.mesh.*;
import toxi.processing.*;
TriangleMesh mesh;
ToxiclibsSupport gfx;
void setup() {
  size(600,600,P3D);
  mesh=(TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(sketchPath("check.stl"),STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);
  gfx=new ToxiclibsSupport(this);
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  lights();
  translate(width/2,height/2,0);
  rotateX(mouseY*0.01);
  rotateY(mouseX*0.01);
  gfx.origin(new Vec3D(),200);
  noStroke();
  gfx.mesh(mesh,false,10);
}
```

> Error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLException
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.createPGL(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1744)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.<init>(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:518)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphics3D.<init>(PGraphics3D.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1919)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1771)
    at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1742)
    at project5.setup(project5.java:27)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361)
    at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: What version of Processing did you install on Raspian (1.5.1, 2.x, etc. ?). Have you tried setting the renderer as OPENGL(```size(600,600,P3D);```) ? Without testing, my guess is toxic libs' ToxiclibsSupport renderer class relies on the OpenGL renderer and in newer versions of Processing I think the P3D and OPENGL renderers are sort of merged. Try with 1.5.1, hopefully it will work. If not, it's still not too bad. I'm assuming the code will run if you comment out the ToxiclibsSupport part and if this is the case, perhaps you can render without it (just using plain Processing calls).

Comment: I used this command `OPENGL(size(600,600,P3D);)` on `Processing-2.2.1` but it give another error `The function OPENGL(void) does not exist.`

Comment: Sorry, I meant use it like this: ```size(600,600,OPENGL);```. Try that, although it might still get the low-level OpenGL errors. Can you try running Examples > Demos > Graphics > LowLevelGL and indicate if the app can run or not (if not, what errors are you getting) ?

Comment: I just run that program `Examples > Demos > Graphics > LowLevelGL` as well, but still I am getting same error...

Comment: I've updated my answer: you can now try Processing with 3D support.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with Processing is that currently there is no 3D implementation because Raspberry PI needs an OPENGL_ES renderer.
Currently you can only render in 2D (e.g. `size(200,200,JAVA2D);`).

There is actually an [OPENGL_ES renderer in Processing](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PGraphics.java) but it's for the Android mode and it has dependencies on the android SDK. As far as I know, there isn't any Processing OPENGL_ES renderer you can use on Raspberry PI at the moment(if someone knows of one, please let me know). In theory how ever, it should be possible to strip out the android dependencies from the Android PGraphics class, but feels like a risky move (especially if you have a tight deadline).To get started you may want to look `EGL` in java running on Rasperry Pi.

I would recommend using [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/download/) instead in this case, if displaying an STL file is all you need. I've modified an existing STL addon for OpenFramworks and tested it: the performance is great on the Raspberry PI. Although it's c++, the project is inspired by Processing and a lot of the functions will sound very familiar.

Once you setup OpenFramworks you can download [ofxSTLModel](https://github.com/orgicus/ofxSTLModel) and compile the example(I've updated it to run on Raspberry PI). Press any key to toggle wireframe view.

[image: ofxSTLModel example preview]

**Update**
Now there is an experimental Raspian image including Processing 3 with 3D support. Check out [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=115350&p=798833)

[image: Processing 3D on Raspberry Pi]